# Mapping composite types from postgresql to ef core

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, composite-types

I defined the following *composite type* in my postgre db:

```sql
CREATE TYPE foobar AS
(
   foo NUMERIC,
   bar NUMERIC
);
```

I have created a struct with the same properties:

```cs
public struct FooBar
{
   public decimal Foo { get; set; }
   public decimal Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And now I would like to use FooBar as such in an entity:

```cs
public class FooyaEntity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public FooBar FooBar { get; set; }
}
```

How would I configure ef core to map these properly? Currently when trying to add something it will yield the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Test.FooBar' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'FooBar' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Also the [documentation for npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html) shows working examples without ef core.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mapping to PostgreSQL composite types isn't yet supported, [this is tracked by this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/22). Anyone interested, please go upvote it!

Comment: Well that's a shame.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: a composite type (in C#) can be "translated" into a table in any database - and then just reference it from other tables. Right?